# onclick event is not working in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and trying to develop a simple react.js application, I am trying a simple alert in javascript by using an `onClick` handler. The `onClick` event is not firing. Here is the code snippet

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
      alertMessage: function() {
        alert(this.props.name);                             
      },

       render: function () {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.alertMessage}>
            Hello {this.props.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you try to this. alertMessage()

Comment: Works well: http://jsfiddle.net/rtkhanas/nqoo7wfv/

Comment: I tried it, apparently it calls the function but says alert is not defined. It seems the code doesn't comprehend javascript elements. Its a jsx file. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @RostyslavKhanas I am using module.exports and not rendering the component explicitlu using ReactDOM.render. Is it because of this that its not working?

Comment: @medha you export you component as a module, but you also need to render this component somewhere, right? Rendering should look the same.

Comment: I am using this component inside some other component, do i still need to render it. When I use a component, doesnt it get rendered automatically?

Comment: Share you complete source code we are not able to figure out with this

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the  alterMessage function to the react component. Because your using props of the react component within function,

> *'this.props'*

bind it as follows,

> this.alertMessage.bind(this)

Comment: It still doesnt work and gives the following warning :You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.

Comment: you mean to say that alert is not getting executed?

Comment: .bind() is only used if you use React in ES6.

Comment: @Calvin oh is it. And I think its not completely about syntax.